# MySQL query: how would one go about issuing a querying a mysql database using Java?

Tags: java, mysql

I have two tables both in the same database...

how would one go about issuing a querying a mysql database using Java?

I need do is to search `LIKE` items `USERNAME` COLUMN in table 1 then take the data from `ID` column and search those against table 2 if the `ID` is found then it returns true if it is not found it returns false

```
TABLE 1:

| Username    |   ID   | 
------------------------
|    Jack     |   3    |
|    Drew     |   2    |
|    jAcK     |   8    |
```

```
TABLE 2:

|   ID   |comment| 
------------------
|   3    |   *   |
|   8    |   *   |
|   2    |   *   |
```

So I guess I should make this more clear:

We search `TABLE 1` for `jack` then all the `IDS` that are found for `LIKE` `jack` are searched against `TABLE 2` if the `ID` is found in `TABLE 2` then `TRUE` if not then `FALSE`

Comment: Can you show the output you expect to get for the given sample input? The question, as it is now, is somewhat unclear (at least to me)

Comment: You need a join here, go thorugh this link once http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/joins.php

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's best to do a little research. There are plenty of resources available about using MySQL from Java programs. Please consider using one of them to get the basics.

Comment: I edited the post so hopefully it clears up the info a little more if I need to add more clarification I will do my best to do so I also appreciate all the help from everyone I did some research even though it doesn't show in my question running on little sleep and gave up...

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1 T1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2
ON T1.ID = T2.ID
WHERE T1.USERNAME = 'USERNAME';
```

Comment: While this might solve OP's problem, it would be much more usefull if you explain why it solves his particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL query itself would look something like this:

```
SELECT t1.USERNAME,
CASE WHEN t2.ID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS HAS_ID
FROM TABLE1 t1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 t2
ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t1.USERNAME LIKE '%Jack%'
```

If the username is not collated to something case-insensitive (look for CI in the collation specification of the column) then you'll need to cast t1.Username and your input string to either lower or upper case.

I'm afraid I can't help you with the java part.